# Access HTML5 Audio Response Headers

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

Is it **in any way** possible, to get access to the HTTP-Response-Headers of an HTML5 Audio Source (so I can read them), in Javascript?

```
<audio id="myaudio" controls>
   <source src="/test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

**EDIT2:**

It seems to be possible, to get access to the headers, with **([service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers))** 
I tried something like:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
   console.log('CLIENT: service worker registration in progress.');
   navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(function(){
      console.log('CLIENT: service worker registration complete.');
     }, function() {
          console.log('CLIENT: service worker registration failure.');
     });
} else {
   console.log('CLIENT: service worker is not supported.');
}
```

My service-worker.js looks like (only as example!):

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
   console.log("SENDING REQUEST: " + event.request.url);
   if(event.request.url === 'https://localhost/test.mp3') {
      event.respondWith(
         fetch(event.request.url, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
               "Authorization": "myToken",
            },
            redirect: "follow"
         }).then(function(response) {
            //check for response header here...
            return response;
         })
      );    
    }
 });
```

The problem I have is, I cannot debug the code (with Firefox 70), it's makes it a little harder to test and I cannot create an final answer...

Comment: When you say "Get access to"... do you mean view them?

Comment: @SeanT: Yes, I want to read the headers (and values).

Comment: @Ben maybe try the `loadeddata` or `loadedmetadata` events? What is `self` in your example?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser from the documentation, these events will not help to get the respond http header.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to view the headers, load the page in chrome and press f12 to open developer tools.

All responses will be under the "Network" tab, click a response and you will see data associated with it (Including http headers).

**Edit**

If you want to do this in js/jquery your best bet is to make an ajax request for each source and then get the response that way.

For example...

```
let url = $('#myaudio').find('source').first().attr('src');

$.ajax({
    //ajax config with `url` for audio source
})
.done(function(response, textStatus, xhr){
    let headers = xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();
});
```

Comment: The question is asking if this can be done in JS, not in general.

Comment: @Amy Oh yeah... I missed the tag. It can be done with ajax so I'll update

Comment: Yes, I am asking about Javascript. Furthermore, I am asking about the Audio-Tag Source. I don't want to request the source **again** with ajax.

Comment: @Ben I'm not aware of another method, surely the response from the audio control is loaded before your javascript compiles on the page? You could try dynamically assigning the source once the js is loaded with an event listener for the responses

Comment: @ben I don't think the `audio` or `source` tags allow you to bind an event handler to the request pipeline; AFAIK, you can only access the headers if you make the request yourself.  It might be possible to bind the result of this request to the audio source, though I am skeptical.

Comment: Did you both heard about `self.addEventListener('fetch'...` ? As far as i know, this could work, but my listener is never called. I am already loading the audio source dynamically in my JS (by setting the source to an url).

Comment: @Ben `fetch` is not a name of an event emitted by those elements.  Yes, of course I have heard of `addEventListener`...

Comment: `fetch` is part of service workers. see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent

Comment: @ben I'm aware.  Those elements do not emit that event.

Comment: What do you mean with "those elements"? please see my edited question.

Comment: Your question contains 2 HTML elements, neither of which emits that event.